# How do I make an array output strings sequentially instead of randomly

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Here is the code

```
function salert_get_name() {
    $rand_name = $this->salert_settings['popup-names'];     
    $text_array = explode(',',$rand_name);
    $name = array_rand($text_array,1); 

    return $text_array[$name];
}    

function salert_get_country(){
    $rand_country = $this->salert_settings['popup-countries'];
    $country_array = explode(',',$rand_country);
    $country = array_rand($country_array,1);

    return $country_array[$country];
}
```

That is I want the first name and first country in my array to match

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Could you include the contents of `$this->salert_settings['popup-names']` and `$this->salert_settings['popup-countries']`in your question?

Comment: If you want the name and the country to match you need to use `array_rand` only once - you should combine those 2 function to 1 or choose random key outside the function and pass it as parameter

Comment: Can you give some input, expected output to elaborate your problem?